# Is it possible to use Apple Music's MusicKit SDK to play user's own station?

Tags: swift, audio-player, apple-musickit, wwdc

I'm trying to allow user's to play user's own station in my app. But after some research, I couldn't figure out whether it's achievable.

As shown below, I want this particular station which Apple Music generated for the user. Does anyone know if Apple make this API public?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the recommendation API, which provides the user's personal station.

```
https://api.music.apple.com/v1/me/recommendations
```

More about it here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/get_default_recommendations